# Using triggers as an SQL aggregate function alternative?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with many millions of rows and will frequently be needing to know the total of one of the columns. Using SUM in queries is way too slow since it requires touching the entire table. Is there a foolproof way to keep an accurate total without calculating it inside each query?

I've thought of using triggers to increment and decrement a stored total when rows are inserted, updated or deleted. One problem with this though (I'm assuming), is that if the table is truncated, then the total wouldn't be brought to zero. I can live with that, but is there anything else to watch out for? Or if there is a better way to go about this, please let me know.

Comment: *Using SUM in queries is way too slow since it requires touching the entire table* Not necessarily, if there's a narrow index that columns you need to produce the total MySQL can use that index.

Comment: you should explore the real indexing capabilities for yours tables  before evaluating triggers

Comment: You may want to check computed columns

Comment: @ta.speot.is Could you elaborate on that? I was under the impression that an index wouldn't have anything to do with a SUM.

Comment: @scaisEdge Could you also elaborate? We need the query to run almost instantly, not just cut the time down, if that's what you mean.

Comment: without tables dimension, cardinality and data structure is difficulto to say  .. but in most case a proper data indexing  allow interesting performance without  .. denomalization ..  so .. you have already a proper answer ..  then you should follow the Bill Karwin recomandation  ..

Comment: @TheGameiswar It looks like computed columns are more for doing computations on a single row, to fill a field within that row. We need a computation on the whole table. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @DaiBu:sorry,i missed context in the question, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, a trigger can keep a summary table updated accurately, as long as:

- You don't disable the trigger
- You don't update the summary table directly
- You don't make changes to the source data through TRUNCATE TABLE (as you noted)

Also:

- You must seed the summary table with a correct initial value
- You must use InnoDB for both the source table and the summary table, so updates are atomic

Maintaining a summary table is one example of [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). As with all denormalization, this risks data anomalies. You're responsible for maintaining data integrity; the database is limited in how much it can help you do that.

I recommend that you need to double-check the summary table from time to time (e.g. hourly may be enough) to make sure it has not gone out of sync, and correct it if it has. It's up to you to do this, because the database can't check it for you.

Comment: Ok, that provides some piece of mind. And yeah, checking to make sure it's in sync every so often is a great idea. Thanks Bill.